# How to transfer score from Game Scene to GameViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, swift2

I created share button for share my score in Facebook , twitter and more. 
the button created in GameViewController and my score and high score i created in Game Scene.

I did share score but i don't know how to transfer my score from GameScene to GameViewController.

**The Score and High Score in Game Scene :**

```
func addPointsLabels() {

        pointsLabel = MLPointsLabel(num: 0)
        pointsLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        pointsLabel.fontName = "Avenir Next Bold"
        pointsLabel.fontSize = 40.0
        pointsLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.view!.frame.size.width/2, self.view!.frame.size.height/2 + 180)
        pointsLabel.name = "pointsLabel"
        addChild(pointsLabel)

        highscoreLabel = MLPointsLabel(num: 0)
        highscoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 161.0/255.0, blue: 156.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        highscoreLabel.name = "highscoreLabel"
        highscoreLabel.fontSize = 25.0
        highscoreLabel.fontName = "Avenir Next Bold"
        highscoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.view!.frame.size.width/2 + 90, self.view!.frame.size.height/2  + 100)
        addChild(highscoreLabel)

    }
```

**GameViewController :**

```
     class scene: SKScene {
        var currentScore: Int = 0
        var highScore: Int = 0

        func updateScore(withScore score: Int) {
            currentScore = score
            highScore = currentScore > score ? currentScore : score
        }
    }

    class GameViewController: UIViewController , MyGameDelegate {

        var scene: GameScene!
        var ShareButton = UIButton()
        var myDelegate : MyGameDelegate!



        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Configure the view
            let skView = view as! SKView
            //skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false
            // Create and configure the scene
            scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    //        NSLog("width: %f", skView.bounds.size.width)
    //        NSLog("height: %f", skView.bounds.size.height)

            // Present the scenee
            skView.presentScene(scene)

        }

        func addShareButton() {
            ShareButton.hidden = false
        }

        override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    //        //create Share Button
            ShareButton = UIButton.init(frame: CGRectMake(self.view!.frame.size.width/2 - 80, self.view!.frame.size.height/2 + 60, 60, 60))
            ShareButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ShareButton.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            ShareButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressedShareButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

            self.view!.addSubview(ShareButton)
        }


func pressedShareButton(sender: UIButton!) {

        // Now you can get your score and high score like this:
        let currentScore = scene.pointsLabel
        let highScore = scene.highscoreLabel

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view!.frame.size, false, 0.0)
        view!.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view!.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        let myText = "WOW! I made \(currentScore) points playing #RushSamurai! Can you beat my score? https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rush-samurai/id1020813520?ls=1&mt=8"

        let activityVC:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myText,image], applicationActivities: nil)

        //New Excluded Activities Code
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint]
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint ]
        }

        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = ShareButton.frame
        presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**MLPointsLable :**

```
class MLPointsLabel: SKLabelNode {

    var number = 0

    //var gameoverscore = 0

    init(num: Int) {
        super.init()

        fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        fontName = "Avenir Heavy"
        fontSize = 24.0

        number = num
        text = "\(num)"
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func increment() {
        number++
        text = "\(number)"


    }


    func setTo(num: Int) {
        self.number = num
        text = "\(self.number)"
```

}

Comment: Can you specify what's the relation between the GameViewController and your GameScene? Does your GameViewController have a reference to the GameScene?

Comment: Yes, GameViewController present my GameScene.

Comment: I try to share my score I got the game on Twitter and Facebook but I do not know how to move the score from Game Scene to GameViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your GameViewController is presenting your GameScene you can just hold a reference to it and get the score and high score from properties in your GameScene.

Something like this:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    var gameScene: GameScene!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Hold a reference to your GameScene after initializing it.
        gameScene = SKScene(...)
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var currentScore: Int = 0
    var highScore: Int = 0

    func updateScore(withScore score: Int) {
        currentScore = score
        highScore = currentScore > score ? currentScore : score
    }
}
```

**Update:**

You could use this values in your `pressedShareButton` like this:

```
func pressedShareButton(sender: UIButton!) {
    let currentScore = scene.currentScore
    let highScore = scene.highScore
    ...
    let myText = "WOW! I made \(currentScore) points playing #RushSamurai! Can you beat my score? https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rush-samurai/id1020813520?ls=1&mt=8"
    ...
```

}

Comment: ok , thanks you. you know how to do it with Delegate ? because in using with delegate or post

Comment: You'd need to use a delegate if you'd want to communicate something back (in the other direction). For example if the GameScene would need the GameViewController to do something you could use a delegate to communicate this, but in this case the communication starts in the GameViewController, so it's going directly from A -> B and not B -> A, so a delegate doesn't make sense here IMHO.

Comment: im understand , thanks you :)  but not works perfectly i will edit my post now.

Comment: if i want to using with my vars (points lable and high score lable) how i can change it to my what i need?

Comment: I see that you updated your question. The problem is your accessing the pointsLabel and highScoreLabel but you need to access the currentScore and highScore properties from your GameScene instead. This will be Ints, but you can convert them to String by doing `String(currentScore)` or append them to another String like this `"This is an example of \(currentScore) appending"`

Comment: you can write correct question and you can using with my code.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to use this values inside your `pressedShareButton` method. See how I'm using currentScore and not currentScoreLabel. You don't need to access the Label from your GameViewController, but only the currentScore property.

Comment: for score i have reference it called MLPointsLable. i want to using with my reference and with what that i created in game scene (points lable) to do it

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that instead of getting this information from your `MLPointsLable` is to have a reference to your points in a Int. Look how `GameScene` is implemented in my example. In the `updateScore` you'd update both your currentScore and your MLPointsLable. If you really want to get the information from your label, you could just do `currentScoreLabel.text` and that will return the text in your label, but I'd recommend against doing this.